# How can I prevent specific updates from appearing in Update Manager's list of updates in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, update-manager

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. When I open Update Manager it comes up with the updates. Some of the updates that are listed are either not relevant to me or I just don't want them.

If I untick them, they just reappear the next time the Update Manager is used.

If I decide I don't want or don't need an update, how can I stop the Update Manager from including it in the list of updates the next time it is used?

Answer (score 1):

Use the terminal command `sudo apt-get install {specific-package}` to update only `{specific-package}` and the packages which it depends on.

Comment: Hi there thank you for the fast reply.

I want to do it the other way around, I am not looking to upgrade a specific update, I want to stop the Update Manager re presenting me with upgrades I de selected (and did not want in the previous session)  If I un tick it I don't want it to come up again in the the next  Update Manager.
Thank you

Comment: Actually, the Ubuntu `upgrade` command does not accept any parameters. If you want to update specific packages you use the `install` command even if the package is already installed. For example, `sudo apt-get install zenity` will update the zenity package and also any package which zenity has a dependency relationship with. `sudo apt-get upgrade zenity` will attempt to apply all outstanding, non-distribution updates.

Answer (score 1):

[Disabling packages from the update manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24871/disabling-packages-from-the-update-manager)  has a bit more info and shows you how to do it via the GUI and CLI.

I would lock the packages you're not interested in to the version you're at.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use the techniques described in the link provided in [*csgeek's answer*](https://askubuntu.com/a/133998/52923) or in [this article](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) to pin or hold packages, I still would not recommend that anyone other than a very experienced user do this. The dependency relationships between packages can be complex and are not always obvious.

I am leaving this answer, which suggests removing a package you do not use, in place as a possible alternative which might also be useful in some cases.

But I want to make it clear that removing a package should only be done if you are **certain** that **no other package you *do* use depends on it!**

For example, I use *gmail* so I have no use for *thunderbird*. I can (safely, I think) open a terminal window and use
`sudo apt-get remove thunderbird`
to uninstall *thunderbird* and avoid downloading and installing updates for it.

But **BE CAREFUL**. If you remove/uninstall a package which other packages use then you could break your Ubuntu installation. Depending on how badly you break it, you might not be able to easily recover.

If removing a package will result in a large number of additional packages **also being removed**, I do **not** think you should do it. In my opinion, you are likely to break something.

I would also suggest that before you remove a package you use the `--assume-no` option on `apt-get` as, for example,
`sudo apt-get -V --assume-no remove thunderbird`

This command will run `apt-get` but will not perform the remove. However, it *will* list the actions which would be taken if you did remove the package. This will give you the opportunity to reflect on how much possible damage removing a package might cause.

(*Note:* the `-V` option in the command above just provides more information about the specific version of the packages `apt-get` might change.)